# TFS Branching and Parenting

Tags: tfs, branching-and-merging

I am currently looking at a solution in TFS which has an odd structure. This in turn means we have an additional redundant step when merging, and I'd like to neaten it up, but I'm not sure how, or even what the best move would be.

We have a Main branch, which contains two child branches Current Release and Current Sprint. Merging between Current Release and Current Sprint requires that everything is merged up to Main first, then back down to the desired child. I would like to remove Main, and make it a one step merge.

Firstly, I suppose, the question is, is this a sensible move? I know that it will simplify the merging process, but don't know if there would be a good reason to keep things as is.

Secondly, Is it actually possible to change the parent of one sibling to that of another sibling? And if so, how do I do it? On top of this, which should be the parent in the relationship? My first instinct is to have Current Release (parent) -> Current Sprint (child).

Can anyone offer any insight on this, as TFS setup is not my strongest area?

Thanks